# How to get rid of sequence numbers in front of WiFi SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

Whenever I connect to my WiFi network, my computer for some reason add a counter value to the Network's name.

For example, if I'm connected to Resident Evil. The next time I reconnect to the same network (after a reboot or something), the network name would become "Resident Evil 1" and so on... It has now reached 121 and counting.

Note that this doesn't happen with other networks until today, when I connected to a personal hotspot started by my phone. But that only went upto 2 and stopped there.

I have tried deleting the network and reconnecting a thousand times. Doesn't do anything.

Any fixes?